# expire certain cookies after specific amout of inactivity time

Tags: php, cookies

i wonder, how i can remove all certain cookies after (e.g. : 10 minutes) inactivity .

im working on securing a php project and one of the steps are this

i should remove administration cookies and session saved in mysql  after certain amount inactivity time in php/mysql project

is there any suggestion  !?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should never be storing anything important in cookies, so you should really only have a Session ID stored as a cookie.

Simply set that cookie to expire in 10 minutes.  Store that same timestamp in your database.

After, say,  5 minutes, do what you need to do, then set the cookie to expire in another 10 minutes and update the session

After, say, 11 more minutes, the cookie won't be provided, and you can forward the user to your "not authenticated page".

In a cron job or on every page load, delete any sessions that have an expiry time in the past.

Comment: @Pickle: I was with you right up to the point where you suggested trying to manage the sessions using cron. While session data can persist beyond the time when it is deemed to have expired, the session handler should recognise this and deny access.

Comment: Yes, certainly.  I was only suggesting that to keep the size of the database down.  There's no need to keep a session key around that expired a week ago, so you might as well delete it.

Answer (score 0):

save a random string both in cookie and in db, in db also save the expire time..
when a client perform a request  get the string from cookie and check the concerning expire time in db... 
if time is passed destroy the cookie, otherwise not...

```
<?php

  //retrive cookies if exist the hash stored in it.
  //cookie don't exist save the cookie
  if(!$_COOKIE){
     //create a random string in $rnd_string and the expire date in $data
     setcookie("hash", $rnd_string);
     //sql connection here
     //adding rows to db..
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (expiredate, hash) VALUES ('".$data."','".$rnd_string."')");
  }
  else{
   //here the code if cookie exist
   $hash=$_COOKIE['hash'];
   //sql connection here
   //retrieving row from db
   $result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT expiredate FROM table WHERE hash='".$hash."'"));
   //in $result['expiredate'] you'll have the expire date, check this with server time and decide if is session is valid or not...        
  }
```

Comment: updated the answer with a simple stupid code.. but it's an example and  I hope it can be useful for you...

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just set the cookies on every page to expire in 10 * 60?